# STM32F4 I/O Max Voltage Input

Tags: stm32, gpio, pins

I'm having trouble understanding the max voltage input voltage range for an I/O pin on a stm32F11 when powering it with 3.3V.I'm want my STM32 to communicate with a 3.3V input signal and need to know if the GPIO and rx/tx UART lines are 3.3V tolerant. Looking over the absolute max specs in the data sheet it looks like they are rated to 4V? I expected to see a table that specifically listed GPIO pins, not "any other pin":
[image]

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/STM32F411RET6/497-14909-ND/4935722

Comment: Link unambiguously to the data sheet that the extract came from.

Comment: Your question does not make sense, if you power the MCU with 3.3V, IO will obviously be 3.3V tolerant. Some pins are 5V tolerant. Did you mean to ask that?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong table - what you have there is in "6.2 Absolute Maximum Ratings", and if you read the paragraph immediately above that table you'll see "These are stress ratings only and functional operation of the device at these conditions is not implied. Exposure to maximum rating conditions for extended periods may affect device reliability". You need "6.3 Operating Conditions".

Comment: @brhans Are you sure OP looks at the wrong table? OP writes: **Looking over the absolute max specs** in the data sheet it looks like they are rated to 4V"*

Comment: @Huisman - looking at the "Absolute Max" is exactly what the problem is. They're *not* the normal operating specs and as the datasheet says: "These are stress ratings only and **functional operation of the device at these conditions is not implied**. Exposure to maximum rating conditions for extended periods may affect device reliability"

Comment: @brhans I know that stuff. Can you please motivate your claim/suggestion OP wants to use the device using these max ratings as operating conditions?

Comment: @Huisman - Why would the OP be looking at, posting, and referring to the "Absolute Max" table if this is not what he thought he should be using? These specs are not relevant to the rest of the question unless the OP wants to stress his STM32 (which I'm assuming he does not). He clearly wants to know what the safe operating conditions are - in which case it's the data in section 6.3 "Operating Conditions" which is relevant and not 6.2 "Absolute Maximum Ratings".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The I/O pins are specifically mentioned. It's the line
`Input voltage on FT and TC pins`

[image]

Check table 7 for the meaning of FT and TC, and the following table 8 to see most UART pins are 5 V tolerant I/O.

[image]

As brhans correctly addresses in a comment, OP and this answer show the Absolute Maximum Ratings.
Any device should be operated within its Operating Conditions, for this device being:

[image]

It confirms the 5V tolerant pins as written above.

Comment: Table 11 is the wrong one - that's "Absolute Maximum Ratings", not "Operating Conditions"

Comment: @brhans Although I didn't mention anything about Abs max ratings and Operating conditions (I just was quoting OP picture) you're right the answer should point out a device should be operated within its Operating Conditions.